# Quantum circuit for a $3$-qubit $|W \rangle$ state

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

Can someone specify a *quantum circuit* that will deterministically output the $3$-qubit $|W \rangle$ state, if the input to the circuit is $|0,0,0 \rangle$? Or, is there a quantum circuit with a different $3$-qubit input state that will output the $3$-qubit $|W \rangle$ state deterministically? I am looking for an abstract description, devoid of any physical system. If this is contained in a reference, one can just list the reference.

For those not familiar with the representation of the $3$-qubit $|W \rangle$ state in the computational basis, it is:

$$|W \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \bigg( |0,0,1\rangle + |0,1,0\rangle + |1,0,0\rangle \bigg) .$$

Generalizations to the $n$-qubit case would also be greatly appreciated. For clarity on the allowable gates in the circuit, please use either $1$-qubit or $2$-qubit gates. Also, it'd be fine if the answer used a $3$-qubit gate such as Toffoli or Fredkin (and these $3$-qubit gates would not need to be further decomposed).

Comment: You should specify what gates you're prepared to accept in your quantum circuit for your question to be well-posed. Otherwise, I could just say "let $U$ be the three-qubit gate that takes ..." and it would be a valid answer. Presumably you want to rule that out, but unless you provide actual hard lines, you're just making people guess at what you'll find acceptable or not.

Comment: OP probably wants it using single and double qubit gates.

Comment: Emilio this seems pedantic, but I see your point. @biryani thanks, you got what I was after.

Comment: What does W stand for in W-state?

Comment: @W.Voltera perhaps "Wolfgang," since the state emanates from https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0005115.pdf

Comment: I came here with the same question, seeking any "reasonable" gate set, i.e. doable in real life. This one does the trick https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit={%22cols%22:[[%22H%22,%22H%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[%22X%22,%22X%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22],[%22X%22,%22X%22,1,%22|0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80|%22],[1,%22X%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[%22X%22,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22],[%22Amps3%22],[],[%22Density3%22]]}

Answer (score 10):

Given a gate schema $G(p) = \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{1-p} & -\sqrt{p} \\ \sqrt{p} & \sqrt{1-p} \end{bmatrix}$, you can use $G(1/3)$ to make a circuit that does the trick.

First you make a balanced superposition of three states. Any three states. That's where the $G(1/3)$ comes in. We'd also need a $G(1/2)$ but $H$ will do the trick. Second, you permute the states so the non-zero amplitudes are on the states you want.

For example, I created [a W-state circuit in my quantum simulator Quirk](http://algorithmicassertions.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22~1b3%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance3%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance3%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance3%22%5D%5D%2C%22gates%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22~1b3%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22G(1%2F3)%22%2C%22matrix%22%3A%22%7B%7B%E2%88%9A%E2%85%94%2C-%E2%88%9A%E2%85%93%7D%2C%7B%E2%88%9A%E2%85%93%2C%E2%88%9A%E2%85%94%7D%7D%22%7D%5D%7D). The inline state displays make it a bit easier to see what's going on:

[image: W-state circuit]

$G(1/3)$ is not really a "standard" gate. Since I didn't want to [use some crazy mix of allowed gates to approximate it](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0505030), I just defined it as a custom gate:

[image: Defining the gate]

**But** as the comments on the question point out, you can also just directly define a gate that maps straight from $|000\rangle$ to the W-state. The core of whether this problem is easy or hard, whether it requires approximations or can be done exactly, is the question *what gates do you allow yourself*?

[image: 0-to-W gate definition]